# How to convert span to flat list of indices?

Tags: list-manipulation, conversion, index

Let `sp` be a `Span` object, and `n` a non-negative integer.

I'm looking for an efficient way to generate the *list* `ii` of indices such that the expressions

```
x[[sp]]
x[[ii]]
```

produce identical results, for all lists `x` of length `n`.

E.g., the desired conversion for `sp = 3;;7` and `n = 7` would be

```
{3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
```

One generally very inefficient (but admirably straightforward) way to generate the list `ii` is with the expression

```
Range[n][[sp]]
```

---

Conceptually it is not difficult to envision how to compute such a mapping, but a full implementation would be tedious, since `Span` has so many variants.

Comment: Try `Range @@ sp` (see also the `Apply` function).

Comment: @user16054: one problem: there are cases where this conversion requires knowledge of `n`...  E.g. when `sp = 3;;`.

Comment: `Range @@ Replace[sp, All -> n, {1}]`

Comment: (See comments in MB1965's answer below); to get correct behavior when the 3rd argument is `All`: 
`Range @@ Replace[
   If[Length[s] == 3 && s[[3]] === All, ReplacePart[s, 3 -> -1], s],
   All -> n,
   {1}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick example of how you could build it without using [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html):

```
spanConvert[n_Integer,
   Span[start : _Integer | All : 1,
    end : _Integer | All : All,
    step : _Integer | All : 1]] :=
  With[{
    s = Replace[Replace[start, All -> n], i_?Negative :> (n - i)],
    e = Replace[Replace[end, All -> n], i_?Negative :> (n - i)]
    },
   With[{p = Replace[step, All -> If[s <= e, 1, -1]]},
    Range[s, e, p]
    ]
   ];
spanConvert[list_, span_Span] := spanConvert[Length@list, span];
spanConvert /: Part[x_, spanConvert[span_Span]] :=

 spanConvert[x, span]
```

Then:

```
x[[spanConvert[1 ;; ;; 2]]]
```

will dump the parts being taken, e.g.:

```
In[83]:= RandomReal[1, 10][[spanConvert[1 ;; ;; 2]]]

Out[83]= {1, 3, 5, 7, 9}
```

Comment: This will fail for (legal) spans like `1 ;; All ;; All` or `All ;; All ;; All`.

Comment: What does a step of `All` mean? If it's just one that's a trivial replacement. And I assume the `All` at the beginning just maps back to `1` so that's trivial too.

Comment: No, it's a bit more complicated. `;; All` gets converted to `1 ;; All` on input, but a span `All ;; All` is valid and is equivalent to `n ;; n`. I believe my comment on the original post (`Range @@ Replace[sp, All -> n, {1}]`) reproduces the correct values.

Comment: @user16054 It fails for things like `All;;5;;All` when n is 10 (but so does mine).

Comment: Ahh, good catch; it also seems that `Range[10][[1 ;; All ;; All]]` is an error; though I'm not sure why.

Comment: @user16054 I updated to do some more sophisticated checking. This `Range[10][[spanConvert[All ;; 5 ;; All]]]` now works for me.

Comment: @user16054 it seems the end parameter is just converted to a `-1`. This throws the same error: `Range[10][[1 ;; -1 ;; All]]`. `All` converts itself to a `-1` as the end is smaller than the start. See: `Range[10][[1 ;; -1 ;; -1]]`

Comment: @MB1965 Despite this behavior being undocumented, it looks like a bug to me: a correct implementation wouldn't touch `All` as the third argument and decide whether it is `1` or `-1` only inside of `Part` (where the complete number of elements is known).

Comment: In the above solution the two occurrences of `i_?Negative :> (n -i)` need to be replaced by `i_?Negative :> (n + i + 1)`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a souped up version of @b3m2a1's answer that supports [`UpTo`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpTo), corrects a couple bugs, and adds error messages. I used the name `Inspantiate` because I couldn't resist (probably something like `FromSpan` would be better):

```
Inspantiate[max_, span_Span] := Module[{res = Catch[iList[max, span], "SpanFailure"]},
    res /; res =!= $Failed
]

iList[max_, span:Span[a_, b_, c_:1]] := Module[{x, y, z},
    x = Replace[a,
        {
        n_Integer :> If[Abs@n>max || n==0,
            Message[Inspantiate::take, a, b, HoldForm[Range[1,max]]];
            Throw[$Failed, "SpanFailure"],
     Mod[n, max+1]
 ],
 All -> 1,
 UpTo[n_Integer?Positive] :> Min[n,max],
 _ :> (Message[Inspantiate::span, span]; Throw[$Failed, "SpanFailure"])
        }
    ];
    y = Replace[b,
        {
        n_Integer :> If[Abs@n>max || n==0,
            Message[Inspantiate::take, a, b, HoldForm[Range[1,max]]];
            Throw[$Failed, "SpanFailure"],
     Mod[n, max+1]
 ],
 All -> max,
 UpTo[n_Integer?Positive] :> Min[n,max],
 _ :> (Message[Inspantiate::span, span]; Throw[$Failed, "SpanFailure"])
        }
    ];
    z = Replace[c,
        {
        All -> If[x<=y, 1, -1],
        Except[_Integer] :> (Message[Inspantiate::span, span]; Throw[$Failed, "SpanFailure"])
        }
    ];
    Range[x,y,z]
]
```

Bug fixes:

```
spanConvert[10, All;;All]
Inspantiate[10, All;;All]

Range[10][[All;;All]]
```

> {10}
>
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
>
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}

```
spanConvert[10, -5;;]
Inspantiate[10, -5;;]

Range[10][[-5;;]]
```

> {}
>
> {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
>
> {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}

Error messages:

```
Inspantiate[3, 5;;7]
Range[3][[5;;7]]
```

> Inspantiate::take: Cannot take positions 5 through 7 in Range[1,3].
>
> Inspantiate[3, 5 ;; 7]
>
> Part::take: Cannot take positions 5 through 7 in {1,2,3}.
>
> {1, 2, 3}[[5 ;; 7]]

If you come across a [`Span`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Span) specification where `Inspantiate` behaves differently from `Range[span]`, please let me know.