# How to convert a slice expression to a Table?

Tags: list-manipulation, intervals

I have an expression

```
slice=5;;7
```

and want to convert it into a list:

```
list={5,6,7}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `list = Range @@ slice`

Comment: Duplicate of this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/146268/45431)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
span = 5 ;; 7;

Range @@ span
```

or

```
Apply[Range] @ span
```

> ```
> {5, 6, 7}
> ```